# How can do Load Test against WebSocket?

Tags: networking, security, ddos, load-testing, websocket

We will have to do a load test for the first time. To tell the truth, I don't know exactly what to look for and how to do it. I have also researched resources on this subject but I could not obtain enough information on the internet and I wanted to ask you here. To summarize my questions, the following items may appear:

- What are the pre-test needs for WebSocket Load Test?
- What are the tools available for testing?
- What should be paid attention to and what content should be created in the report to be created after the test?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 free and open source load testing tools which support Websocket protocol load testing:

1. [Gatling](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/websocket/)
2. [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/features.html#websocket-related-features)
3. [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) with [WebSocket Samplers plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)

With regards to your "pre-test needs" and "What should be paid attention to" - there is only one strict rule: well-behaved load test must exactly represent real life application usage so you need to carefully and properly simulate the same network footprint as the real user (or another system) has, just at bigger scale.